# Saving User Data without Password - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to save a user's data from an admin account on my site, but I receive the error that the current password can't be blank after the form submits. Here is the form I'm using:

`= form_for @user, url: { action: 'update', controller: 'devise/registrations'}, method: :put do |f|`

It would work successfully if it did not validate the user first.

Comment: try this   ``user.update(validate: false, your_field: "blabla")``

Comment: Make sure the form doesn't have a password field. I think you do. If you remove the field you should be fine. Otherwise submit to your own controller and handle the situation separately.

Comment: Ithink you have to post to user/update instead of devise controller.

Comment: It's more than just one field, and I'm using the Devise Registrations controller. Do I need to override it?

Comment: Try calling `update_without_password` on your user: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable:update_without_password

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to rails. How would I implement this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in `application_controller.rb` as its mention in `devise` doc

```
  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :role, :email, :password])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:email,:#foo, :bar])
    end
```

you can modify your column name for signup and update action for devise.

Comment: I'm already using those parameters for every column. I removed the one for `:current_password` and `:confirm_password`, but I still get the same error.